# Need help in translating "cuciture armate" (armed seams?)

Tags: phrase-request, translation, terminology

I need your help with  translating the Italian builder's term  "**cucitura armata**" in English, preferably the term should be technical.

They are steel or iron rods inserted in structures which are at risk of collapsing.

I've checked using Google but it yielded only [21 results](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22cucitura%20armata%22&rlz=1C1AOHY_enIT708IT709&biw=1366&bih=634&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjG6qCo15PPAhWHAcAKHU6vCgIQ_AUIBygA&dpr=1#q=%22cucitura%20armata%22%20in%20English&start=10) for ‘"cucitura armata" in English’, and as far as I could see, the English equivalent is nowhere to be seen. I checked with [Word Reference](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/cucitura%20armata) but it only translated the term *cucitura* as "seam", "stitching" and "stapling". The private student whose work I am correcting, had written **armed seam**, but  until she explained, I had no idea what it meant.  I am not very convinced that *armed seams* describes the procedure or the name of this structural intervention.

Please, see Google [images](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22armed%20seam%22&rlz=1C1AOHY_enIT708IT709&biw=1366&bih=634&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvs_Gy75PPAhUqLMAKHTsRCLM4ChD8BQgGKAE) for *armed seam*, only images of cricketers and American footballers are displayed.

Here are a few images of "cuciture armate" to help clarify

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source of images: *[Consolidamento e restauro](http://www.mincioni.it/index.php)*

Please help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The metal rods which form the skeleton of concrete pillars and beams are known in the UK as REINFORCING RODS and in North America as REBAR (reinforcing bar).

These rods are widely used in construction rather than simply securing structures at risk of collapse. But the same name may apply.

Metal straps that are used to bind objects, as in your top illustration, are known as STEEL STRAPPING.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebar
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strapping

Comment: Thank you, so much! Just to double check, are these the same rods or bars used in works of conservation and restauration?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have no experience of conservation and restoration work but I imagine that the answer is yes.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. Rebar is reinforcing rod, often placed inside wet concrete. It could be used as a component in the sort of supporting structures shown in your pictures. But they would not be called "rebars". We'd say "It was reinforced with rebar." (non-count)